# a number N and a digit P . Your task is to find the count of numbers from range 1 to N (inclusive) which do not have digit P in them

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

I am unable to find what's the theory behind it cause brute force will not give an answer in efficient way cause n can vary up to 10^18, so loop each number isn't a good approach. I searched google entirely but didn't get any theory behind it. all i want to know is what number theory is behind it. using combination for individual digit will also be a hell solution. there were programs but i didn't get them. so please let me know what's theory or concept it is based on. just let me know the topic. thank you

Comment: Well, I don't know about math but I can help you with a program for this task. This particular category of problems comes under digit DP. You can google, there is plenty of material on it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion, I'll work on it. really thank you